# MultipleSelectorRow in Eureka forms (Swift) how to Cast FormValues to String array?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Can someone help me with retrieving the value from MultipleSelectorRow of Eureka forms?

I have a Multiple Select row like this, which lists the floors.

```
  <<< MultipleSelectorRow <String> {
            $0.title = "  *Floor"
            $0.tag = "floor"
            $0.options = floorArray
            $0.validationOptions = .validatesOnChange
            $0.add(rule: RuleRequired())
            }.onPresent { from, to in
               to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(SRElementsForInspectionVC.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
            }.cellUpdate({(cell , row) in
                if !row.isValid{
                    // CELL BORDER HAS TO BE RED
                 cell.textLabel?.textColor = .red

                } else {
                    // do something
                }
            })
```

Then when I try to retrieve the values on submit button I call ,

```
let formvalues = self.form.values()
    if let floor = formvalues["floor"]{
        if floor != nil{
            print(floor)

            for f in floor as! [String: Any] {
                let fl = f as! String
                print(fl)
                // Print the floor
            }

        }
    }
```

But I can't get the correct casting. Please help.

> Optional(Set(["4", "1", "3", "2"]))
>   Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Set' (0x7fe07537f348) to 'Swift.Dictionary' (0x10999ed38).
>   2019-01-30 12:48:36.283692+0530 SIDERISE[22242:772718] Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Set' (0x7fe07537f348) to 'Swift.Dictionary' (0x10999ed38).

Answer (score 0):

yes you fix this like this

```
if let _floors = formvalues["floor"] as? Set<String> {
      for _floor in _floors{
          print(_floor)
      }
}
```

it took me plus a friend 90 mins/2 hours to work this out